# How to check key value id exits or not in array of object in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to check value is exits or not in an array of objects. Please give me a solution if it works then I accept your answer Anyone here with a solution for this? Thanks in Advance. Here is my code.

```
[{"index":0,"productId":"5d9890c7773be00ab5b41701","qty":2}, {"index":0,"productId":"5d9890c7773be00ab5b41701","qty":3}]
```

how to check ProductId is exited or not of this array in Flutter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your List have duplicate value. In my demo, add an extra index 1 to prove it work 
For unique and index only , use indexWhere 
For return qualified list use where , firstWhere, singleWhere 
You can see DarPad result 
code snippet

```
void main()  {

 List<Map> productList = [{"index":0,"productId":"5d9890c7773be00ab5b41701","qty":2}, {"index":0,"productId":"5d9890c7773be00ab5b41701","qty":3},                   {"index":1,"productId":"5d9890c7773be00ab5b41702","qty":23}];

  int index = productList.indexWhere((prod) => prod["productId"]=='5d9890c7773be00ab5b41701' ); 
  print(index);

  var prodLists = productList.where((prod) => prod["productId"] == '5d9890c7773be00ab5b41701');

  print('${prodLists}');

}
```

Output

```
0
({index: 0, productId: 5d9890c7773be00ab5b41701, qty: 2}, {index: 0, productId: 5d9890c7773be00ab5b41701, qty: 3})
```

[image]

Comment: You took List<map> and when I am trying to take in List<String> then how to find a key Please give me a solution for List<String>.

Comment: For List<String> you can use list.contains(x);